# for loop doesnt work very tick

Tags: javascript, html

basic incremental game javascript attempt blah blah http://igt.bitballoon.com/

timer var at top of code

```
var Timer = window.setInterval(function(){Tick()}, 1000);
```

My tick function

```
function Tick() {
    var persec = game.money;
    for (var i = 0; i < buildings.length; i++){
    persec += buildings[i].PerSec * buildings[i].Qty
}
```

the function that i want to work every tick but it does not

```
function Tick() {
    var persec = game.money;
    for (var i = 0; i < buildings.length; i++){
        persec += buildings[i].PerSec * buildings[i].Qty
    }
document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = persec;
}
```

the problem: it changes the persec value on the page when you buy a building and it adds the persec value to your money only once. it does not repeat every tick like it should. i had it working because with some bulky code but i dont want to add a new line for each building. i would prefer something like the for loop. so any help would be appreciated.

edit: website is not up to date sorry. didnt update it cause i wanted it to work first.

Comment: How is `game.money` getting set? Seems like you need to re-set it, because right now you _always_ start from that value every time.

Comment: Side note, I think this type of game are called `idle games` Just wanted to say something cause the word Incremental Game just sounded quite odd.

Comment: idle, incremental, clicker depends on the true functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original

```
function Tick() {
    game.money += buildings[0].Qty * buildings[0].PerSec;
    game.money += buildings[1].Qty * buildings[1].PerSec;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = game.money
}
```

Should be

```
function Tick() {
    buildings.forEach(function(building) {
        game.money += building.Qty * building.PerSec;  
    });
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = game.money;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you want is: 
Instead of

```
persec += buildings[i].PerSec * buildings[i].Qty
```

You should use

```
game.money += buildings[i].PerSec * buildings[i].Qty
```

You are just updating local variable `persec` right now.

Comment: I looked at his source code and it seems that he is doing that. His question is kind of inaccurate to what he has. Excerpt from his actual source code 

`function Tick() {
    game.money += buildings[0].Qty * buildings[0].PerSec;
    game.money += buildings[1].Qty * buildings[1].PerSec;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = game.money
}`